# Does "[player] has disconnected" mean a blocked player has tried to join my game?

Tags: torchlight-2

I frequently block players in TL2 multi-player for being showing a general lack of in-game etiquette (ie, running ahead in the map and killing everything so I get no exp, killing bosses without me, etc).  Oftentimes, I will be playing and will see "[player] has disconnected" without even seeing that the player has connected in the first place.  The names are usually unfamiliar to me, though.   This leads me to believe that blocks are placed at the user account level, so blocking player JohnBoy will still result in MaryGirl being blocked if both characters are controlled by the same user account.

Can anyone confirm that this is why I will see that message?